# Hierarchical query in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, hierarchy

I have access only to the views. I cannot access tables.

Relation view contains metadata in hierarchical format.

Contains

- Column to Table relation
- Table to schema relation
- Table / Schema to database relation
- Table / Schema / Database to System relation

obj id & type and parent obj id & type defines the hierarchy.

Object view contains metadata attributes like object name, type, etc.

Tables can be present within a schema or a database or a system.

Relation returns very huge dataset - in the order of few hundreds of millions. Hence Self join is something which I am trying to avoid.

Version - Microsoft SQL Server 2014
(Some of the functions are not supported)

Relation:

```
+------------+--------------------+------------+---------------------+
| object_id1 | object_type_name1  | object_id2 | object_type_name2   |
+------------+--------------------+------------+---------------------+
| 1          |  table             | 100        |  schema             |
| 100        |  schema            | 200        |  database           |
| 200        |  database          | 300        |  system             |
| 2          |  table             | 201        |  database           |
| 201        |  database          | 301        |  system             |
| 3          |  table             | 302        |  system             |
| 4          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 5          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 6          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 7          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 8          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 9          |  column            | 1          |  table              |
| 10         |  column            | 2          |  table              |
| 11         |  column            | 2          |  table              |
| 12         |  column            | 2          |  table              |
| 13         |  column            | 3          |  table              |
| 14         |  column            | 3          |  table              |
| 15         |  column            | 3          |  table              |
```

obj_Attribute:

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
|  Object_id  |  Object_Name  |  Object_Type  |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| 1           |  Table_A      |  table        |
| 2           |  Table_B      |  table        |
| 3           |  Table_C      |  table        |
| 4           |  Col_A        |  column       |
| 5           |  Col_B        |  column       |
| 6           |  Col_C        |  column       |
| 7           |  Col_D        |  column       |
| 8           |  Col_E        |  column       |
| 9           |  Col_F        |  column       |
| 10          |  Col_G        |  column       |
| 11          |  Col_H        |  column       |
| 12          |  Col_I        |  column       |
| 13          |  Col_J        |  column       |
| 14          |  Col_K        |  column       |
| 15          |  Col_L        |  column       |
| 100         |  Schema1      |  schema       |
| 200         |  DB1          |  database     |
| 201         |  DB2          |  database     |
| 300         |  System1      |  system       |
| 301         |  System2      |  system       |
| 301         |  System3      |  system       |
| 302         |  System4      |  system       |
```

Our requirement is to develop a query that displays metadata in the following format:

Output with Attribute:

```
+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| system  | database | schema  | table   | column |
+---------+----------+---------+---------+--------+
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_A  |
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_B  |
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_C  |
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_D  |
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_E  |
| System1 | DB1      | Schema1 | Table_A | Col_F  |
| System2 | DB2      | ?       | Table_B | Col_G  |
| System2 | DB2      | ?       | Table_B | Col_H  |
| System2 | DB2      | ?       | Table_B | Col_I  |
| System4 | ?        | ?       | Table_C | Col_J  |
| System4 | ?        | ?       | Table_C | Col_K  |
| System4 | ?        | ?       | Table_C | Col_L  |
```

Output with Object ID:

```
+--------+----------+--------+-------+--------+
| system | database | schema | table | column |
+--------+----------+--------+-------+--------+
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 4      |
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 5      |
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 6      |
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 7      |
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 8      |
| 300    | 200      | 100    | 1     | 9      |
| 301    | 201      | ?      | 2     | 10     |
| 301    | 201      | ?      | 2     | 11     |
| 301    | 201      | ?      | 2     | 12     |
| 302    | ?        | ?      | 3     | 13     |
| 302    | ?        | ?      | 3     | 14     |
| 302    | ?        | ?      | 3     | 15     |
```

Could any one please help achieve this output ?

Update: I tried to come up with the query earlier before realizing the data volume - but the query fails with memory issue

```
with objt as (select * from obj_Attribute)

select 
(select object_name from objt where object_id=tbl_id) as tbl_nm,
(select object_name from objt where object_id=col_id) as col_nm,
(select object_name from objt where object_id=schema_id) as sc_nm,
(select object_name from objt where object_id=db_id) as db_nm,
(select object_name from objt where object_id=sy_id) as sy_nm
 
from (
   select 
      tbl.object_id1 as tbl_id,
      col.object_id1 as col_id,
      case when sc.object_type1='Schema' then sc.object_id1 end as schema_id,
      case when db.object_type1='Database' then db.object_id1 
      when sc.object_type1='Database' then sc.object_id1 
      end as db_id,
      case when sy.object_type1='System' then sy.object_id1 
      when db.object_type1='System' then db.object_id1 
      when sc.object_type1='System' then sc.object_id1 
      end as sy_id
   from 
   relation tbl 

   left outer join relation sc
   on tbl.object_id2 = sc.object_id1

   left outer join relation db
   on sc.object_id2 end = db.object_id1

   left outer join relation sy
   on else db.object_id2 = sy.object_id1

   left outer join relation col
   on col.object_id2=tbl.object_id1
   and col.object_type1='Column'

   where tbl.object_type1 in ('Table', 'View', 'Database View')
) subqry
```

Comment: Your query doesn't match your sample data. Please correct. Also you are joining by `Relation.obj_id1` (`object_id` ?) which is not unique. Is it correct?

Comment: Thanks for notifying - I updated the query to match the sample data. Yes - JOINs are based on object_id because the hierarchy can go upto 4 levels - ```Tables to schema to database to system``` and they are not consistent. hence I found no other option

Comment: These two rows, `2   |  table    | 201   |  database` and  `2          |  column    | 1   |  table`, is  it correct? Then you need to join on `object_id1 = .. and object_type_name1=..`

Comment: pardon me - that was incorrect - I updated the data sample now. .

Answer (score 0):

Using self join statring with system level. To get names join `obj_Attribute` at the end.

```
with sys as (
    select * from obj_Attribute where  Object_Type = 'system' 
)
select s.Object_id systemId
   , case 'database' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 end dbId
   , case 'schema' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1  
                   when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1 
     end schemaId
   , case 'table' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 
                  when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1
                  when r3.object_type_name1 then r3.object_id1
     end  tableId
   , case 'column' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 
                   when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1
                   when r3.object_type_name1 then r3.object_id1
                   when r4.object_type_name1 then r4.object_id1
     end  columnId    
from sys s
left join Relation r1 on s.Object_id = r1.object_id2
left join Relation r2 on r1.Object_id1 = r2.object_id2
left join Relation r3 on r2.Object_id1 = r3.object_id2
left join Relation r4 on r3.Object_id1 = r4.object_id2
```

If this is resource consuming you can try doing it in several steps. For example, postponing the last step:

```
with sys as (
    select * from obj_Attribute where  Object_Type = 'system' 
)
select s.Object_id systemId
   , case 'database' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 end dbId
   , case 'schema' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1  
                   when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1 
     end schemaId
   , case 'table' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 
                  when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1
                  when r3.object_type_name1 then r3.object_id1
     end  tableId
   , case 'column' when r1.object_type_name1 then r1.object_id1 
                   when r2.object_type_name1 then r2.object_id1
                   when r3.object_type_name1 then r3.object_id1
     end  columnId
   , r3.object_id1 r3_id1
INTO #Temp
from sys s
left join Relation r1 on s.Object_id = r1.object_id2
left join Relation r2 on r1.Object_id1 = r2.object_id2
left join Relation r3 on r2.Object_id1 = r3.object_id2;
--left join Relation r4 on r3.Object_id1 = r4.object_id2
  
select t.systemId, t.dbId, t.schemaId, t.tableId, coalesce(t.columnId, r4.object_id1) columnId
from #temp t
left join Relation r4 on t.r3_id1 = r4.object_id2;
```

Comment: Thanks Serg. I would have done self joins if it was a table with right set of indexes. Since this is a view- If I do self join - the query runs longer and fails with memory issue

Comment: Alternatively you can try recursive CTE. Not sure it will consume fewer resources. Also you can instantiate the view into a temp table and build indexes.